# SQL select distinct combination of values on multiple columns

Tags: sql

I've checked everywhere for a simple solution to this and I can not find it. Say you have a database

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| function A | function B |
| function B | function A |
| function C | function D |
| function D | function C |
| function E | function F |
| function H | function G |

I want to get rid of the combination of unique values, so I output this

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| function A | function B |
| function C | function D |
| function E | function F |
| function H | function G |

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Is it possible to have unique combinations as well (ex: ColA = 'Fct 3' / ColB = 'Fct 17')? Are the combination always the same, I mean: could 'function 1' be associated to 'function 20' as well?

Comment: Just trying to understand the requirement here - is it the case that you want combination of values from the columns whereas in your source table you have permutation of values?

Comment: Yes, any permutation of values in columns that are not distinct should be discarded

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<`:

```
select t.*
from t
where column_a < column_b;
```

This will select one row from each reversed pair, the one where `column_a` has the lower value.

EDIT:

The question changed after I answered it.  That is pretty rude, but I'll adjust the answer anyway:

```
select t.*
from t
where column_a < column_b or 
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.column_a = t.column_b and
                        t2.column_b = t.column_a
                 );
```

Comment: What if instead of function 1 we have function A, function B, etc?

Comment: Also updated my question to include other non combination rows

Comment: @gordon-linoff :  will this solution work if the example table's 1st or 3rd row are not present.